# separability of exponential function of (x-y) into product of two independent exponential functions of x and y

Tags: functions

Take the following exponential: $e^{f(x-y)}$ where f is a function of the difference of $x$ and $y$, and $x$ and $y$ are Real numbers.

I want to find what functions satisfy the relation:

$e^{f(x-y)} = e^{g(x)} e^{h(y)}$

for example: $e^{x-y} = e^{x} e^{y}$ satisfies the condition, with 
$g(x)=x$ and $h(y)=y$ .

Is there any other function f that satisfy the same condition?

I think what I need to find is equivalent to the condition:
$f(x-y) = g(x) + h(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement holds if and only if $f(x-y)=g(x)+h(y)$ for all x and y, in particular
$$f(0) = g(x) + h(x)$$
implying that $h(x) = f(0) - g(x)$, and we also have
$$f(x)=f(x-0) = g(x) +h(0)$$
We can therefore rewrite
$$f(x-y) = f(0) + g(x) - g(y)=f(0) + f(x)-f(y).$$
implying that $f(x)-f(0)$ is linear, therefore $f(x)=ax+b$ is the only possible solution. Going back to the original problem we see that $e^{a(x-y)+b} = e^{ax+b}e^{-ay}$.